# Trouble Connecting Ports and Subscriptions

Tags: javascript, interop, elm

I am reading through the [Elm guide](http://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/javascript.html) and their JavaScript interOp.  Here is a simplified version:

```
port module FooBar exposing (..)

import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.App as Html
import String

main =
  Html.program
    { init = init
    , view = view
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }

-- subscriptions
port f : () -> Cmd msg
port g : ( Int -> msg ) -> Sub msg

subscriptions: Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model = g Get

-- MODEL
type alias Model = { pt :  Int }

-- VIEW
view: Model -> Html Msg
view model = Html.text ( toString model.pt )

-- UPDATE
type Msg = Ask | Get Int

update: Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd msg)
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Ask  -> (model, f () )
    Get x -> ( Model x, Cmd.none )

-- INIT
init: (Model, Cmd Msg)
init = ( Model 0, f ())
```

The App is initially set to **0** but it should read the message from JavaScript and be set to **1**.  However, it remains at **0**.  Are the Elm ports set up properly?

```
<div id="foobar"></div>
<script src="foo.js"></script>
<script>
  var node = document.getElementById("foobar");
  var app  = Elm.FooBar.embed(node);

  app.ports.f.subscribe(
    function(){
      var myValue = 1;
      console.log(myValue);
      app.ports.g.send(myValue);
    }
  );
</script>

</body>
```

Here I put: `elm-make foo.elm --output=foo.js`

The fact that `myValue` prints to console as **1** suggests the `f()` port got called, but the `g()` port never gets sent back or handled properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to tell if this is a design decision, but `init` is called before `Html.App` is subscribed to any ports.

Therefore calling `f ()` from `init` will have no effect.

I use `send` function, which runs a dummy task and always sends `Ask` message, which will trigger the outgoing port.

Consider changing your `init` to send a message, that sends the data to the port:

```
-- INIT


init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init =
    -- ( Model 0, f ())
    ( Model 0, send Ask )


send : msg -> Cmd msg
send msg =
  Task.perform identity identity (Task.succeed msg)
```

Comment: I don't know enough Elm to make "design decisions"... 

Comment: ooh this is Elm 0.17 so there might be syntax change

Comment: I checked... `f` definitely gets called.  I tried using a `console.log`

Comment: @johnmangual I was referring to the execution order of `Html.app` initialization.

Comment: the docs on [Tasks](http://guide.elm-lang.org/error_handling/task.html) are not up yet - thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are merely looking to send default values from Javascript to your Elm app, you can use [programWithFlags](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/1.0.0/Html-App#programWithFlags), eliminating the need to try to wire into a port that isn't yet set up:

```elm
main =
  Html.programWithFlags
    { init = init
    , view = view
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }

-- INIT
type alias Flags = { initialValue : Int }

init : Flags -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
init flags = ( Model flags.initialValue, Cmd.none )
```

This allows you to send that initial value through Javascript like this:

```js
var app  = Elm.FooBar.embed(node, { initialValue : 2 });
```